# What is the difference between Higher Order Component (HOC) and Inheritance in React native component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I am new to react native from .net background,

Here the Question is how HOC is different from inheritance in OOPS concept by having a parent class with base properties and child that extends the Base and use the state, properties and base methods from the Base class.

Which is the best way to achieve the **Parent-> Child -> GrandChild** hierarchical relationship in React Components .?

For Example:

**Parent.js** Looks like

```js
class Parent extends Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: "Parent",
            BaseText: "Inheritance Example"
        }
    }

    onUpdate = () => {
        console.log("Update called at Parent")
    }
}
```

**Child.js** which extends Parent.js

```js
class Child extends Parent
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
       //this state should inherit the properties of Parent and override only the value property
        this.state = {
            value: "Child",
        }
    }

    onUpdate = () => {
        super.onUpdate();
        console.log("Update called at Child view")
    }



    render()
    {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text> Child View</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

The **GrandChild.js** extends from Child.js

```js
class GrandChild extends Child
    {
        constructor(props)
        {
            super(props);
           //this state should inherit the properties of Child, Parent and properties specific to this
            this.state = {
                value: "GrandChild",
                Name: "Test Grand Child"
            }
        }

        onUpdate = () => {
            super.onUpdate();
            console.log("Update called at Grand Child view")
        }



        render()
        {
            return(
                <View>
                    <Text> Grand Child View</Text>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

Is this the right way of implementing **abstraction** in react native
say Parent class will have the common state properties and the child inherits the Parent state and has its own properties.

**How to inherit state and how to update values to state in this case .?**

Comment: HOCs use composition, https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html . The point of this is similar to OOP's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance . *Which is the best way to achieve the Parent-> Child -> GrandChild hierarchical relationship* - there is no 'best way' because this depends on components. If you have specific case in mind, consider reasking the question with specific code example.

Comment: Sure will modify the Question with sample code snippet.

Comment: Do you have an example that would be more real-world? `this.state` inheritance in child components won't work well with component composition but I cannot think of a good reason to ever do that. If the state becomes that complex, there is possibly a need to use state management (Redux?). Components need to be refactored to fit composition better but I cannot suggest how to do that because it's unclear what components really do. Btw, `onUpdate` doesn't play well with inheritance because it's instance method and there will be no `super.onUpdate`, it should be prototype method.

Comment: Inheritance in JavaScript is prototypal. HOCs are composed functions.

Answer (score 3):

React promotes [composition](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) as an alternative to class inheritance. Components were designed to be efficiently composed. [Hooks API](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) augments function components with features that previously required class components to be used.

This doesn't mean that inheritance isn't allowed. The problem with it is that existing patterns such as higher-order component are widely used in React ecosystem and aren't compatible with OOP:

```
const withBaz = Comp => <Comp baz />

@withBaz
class Bar extends Foo { ... }
```

This approach is common but it isn't OOP friendly because in this case `Bar` is actually not a class anymore but arrow function, it cannot be inherited further.

There are no problems with using OOP for first-party React components as long as a developer controls all components in class hierarchy, but this may be unpractical because there always may be a need to involve third-party code that isn't OOP-friendly. The use of composition where it fits results in more flexible design.

Comment: with composition is it possible to have lifecycle events.?
say Parent class has a ComponentDidMount(), 
rendering Child should call the Componentdidmount of its own and also the lifecycle event of Parent also .?

Comment: componentDidMount will be called in both components if they were mounted (i.e. successfully rendered).

Comment: One last question.

How can i achieve inheritence of state property in Child to use both the Parent and its own state property .?

Comment: You probably don't need. That's why I asked for real-world example. It could be expressed in a way that is idiomatic to React without inheritance. Usually you need to use inheritance only when you need to extend the functionality of third-party class components you cannot modify directly.

Comment: Say for example,
We are building a DataEntry Form(include Input controls, Grids etc..) and the List Form(Includes search control and a Grid) there some common methods like exporting the grid to Excel, Fetching the Records for that grid, state properties such as FormName, GridName. 

So i want those common methods and state properties to be part of the AbstractForm.js this will act as the parent for both DataentryForm.js(the details about input fields are specific to this child) and ListForm.js(details about the search field is specific to this child).

Comment: *there some common methods like exporting the grid to Excel, Fetching the Records for that grid* - there may be no need to have them as class methods, they could be extracted to separate functions. Depending on specific case, common state-specific functionality can be extracted to common functions, or separated from components (Redux, etc), or managed in common parent (see https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).